# Is it possible to put one left outer join within other left outer join

Tags: sql, db2, left-join, join

Can I put a *left outer join* inside another *left outer join*?  Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON (LEFT OUTER JOIN table 3 ON (Join Conditions))
WHERE
....(where conditions)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To group multiple joins, the syntax is as follows (untested on db2)

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
  table2 t2 INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.someId = t2.someId
) ON t2.someId = t1.someId
```

Same syntax for left join inside `LEFT JOIN()`, but please read comment by @X-Zero

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
  table2 t2 LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.someId = t2.someId
) ON t2.someId = t1.someId
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way it works on DB2, as well.  The OP asked for a nested `LEFT` join, but the syntax is otherwise the same.  However, usually it's best to do inner joins, and just let the outer-most left handle those duties (if for no other reason than multiple `LEFT`s can get twisty).

Comment: Thanks @ChrisGessler.. your solution was very useful.. Now i am able to use nested JOINS in my Query.